# How to add a column header below an existing column header in ag-grid for react

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid

Example

```
Header 1      | header 2     | header 3
extra header  | extra header | extra header
-------------------------------------------
row cell 1    | row cell 2   | row cell 3
```

Is this the correct way to do it or is there a more elegant way?

```js
<AgGridReact>
  <AgGridColumn field="Header 1">
    <AgGridColumn field="extra header" />
  </AgGridColumn >
  <AgGridColumn field="Header 2">
    <AgGridColumn field="extra header" />
  </AgGridColumn>
  <AgGridColumn field="Header 3">
    <AgGridColumn field="extra header" />
  </AgGridColumn>
</AgGridReact>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example.
You can create customGroupComponent like that

```
import React from 'react';

export default ({ displayName, extraHeaderName }) => {
  return (
    <div className="ag-header-group-cell-label">
      <div>
        <div>{displayName}</div>
        <div>{extraHeaderName}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

And use it like that

```
<AgGridColumn 
    headerName="header1" 
    headerGroupComponent="customHeaderGroupComponent" 
    headerGroupComponentParams={ {extraHeaderName: "extra header1" } } 
/>
<AgGridColumn 
    headerName="header2" 
    headerGroupComponent="customHeaderGroupComponent" 
    headerGroupComponentParams={ {extraHeaderName: "extra header2" } } 
/>
```

Comment: Thanks. I've asked some other questions on how to set dynamic header height for just one header group. If you want to bump up your rating would appreciate looking at those :)